# How to properly init a sub function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Please consider the following code. This code works as expected.

```
function paging(totalItems, currentPage, itemsPerPage) {
  this.totalItems = (typeof totalItems !== 'undefined') ? totalItems : 0;
  this.currentPage = (typeof currentPage !== 'undefined') ? currentPage : 1;
  this.itemsPerPage = (typeof itemsPerPage !== 'undefined') ? itemsPerPage : 18;
}

function viewModel(foo, bar, paging) {
  this.foo = (typeof foo !== 'undefined') ? foo : true;
  this.bar = (typeof bar !== 'undefined') ? bar : false;
  this.paging = (typeof paging !== 'undefined') ? paging : {};
}

function init() {
  // Create a new viewmodel object and assign it to $scope (AngularJS)
  $scope.viewModel = new viewModel();
  // Set the paging parameter to a new paging object
  $scope.viewModel.paging = new paging();
  // Now we can use dot notation to assign the value in the sub-function
  $scope.viewModel.paging.currentPage = 1;
}

init();
```

Now, what I'm trying to do, and can't quite figure out, is how to call "new viewModel()" and have the paging property automatically populate itself with a new paging(), without having to make the extra call in init(). So, for example, something like this...

```
function viewModel(foo, bar, paging) {
  this.foo = (typeof foo !== 'undefined') ? foo : true;
  this.bar = (typeof bar !== 'undefined') ? bar : false;
  this.paging = (typeof paging !== 'undefined') ? paging : new paging();
}
```

Which throws an error about a constructor if I remember correctly.

I also tried this:

```
function viewModel(foo, bar, paging) {
  this.foo = (typeof foo !== 'undefined') ? foo : true;
  this.bar = (typeof bar !== 'undefined') ? bar : false;
    function paging(totalItems, currentPage, itemsPerPage) {
      this.totalItems = (typeof totalItems !== 'undefined') ? totalItems : 0;
      this.currentPage = (typeof currentPage !== 'undefined') ? currentPage : 1;
      this.itemsPerPage = (typeof itemsPerPage !== 'undefined') ? itemsPerPage : 18;
    }
}
```

... and several other forms of the above, but nothing seems to properly init the paging property except the original example. Isn't there a better way to handle this?

Comment: your parameter `paging` is shadowing the constructor function also called `paging`. You can try and rename the function parameter to something else other than `paging`

Comment: Nick's answer is correct - your `function paging` definition is colliding with the paging definition in `viewModel(foo, bar, paging)`.  Simple workaround, change the functions to uppercase, which is good practice in any case: `function Paging(...` and `function ViewModel(...`